# 하고 _는 Grammatical Structure

Tags: grammar

[image]

I started reading [**a 만화**](http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=651664&no=1&weekday=fri) and came across a sentence that looked like this:

> 오늘 아침도 바압 하고 우는 나초의 보챔으로 눈을 뜹니다.

I understand most of this sentence (talking about how she is waking up to the cries of her cat Nacho). However, I don't understand the usage of "하고" plus "우는". What is this grammatical concept?

Comment: The verb “`하다`” has tons of meanings. This is one of them: `Sense Ⅴ. (의성어 뒤에 쓰여) 그런 소리가 나다. 또는 그런 소리를 내다.`, `Sense Ⅵ. (인용 조사 없이 발화를 직접 인용하는 문장 뒤에 쓰여) 인용하는 기능을 나타내는 말.`.

Answer (score 3):

하고 here is a way of quoting the actual sound made. You can think of it as another member of the 다고 / 라고 / 냐고 / 자고 set of quotationals. It makes sense here because '바압-' is a representation of the actual sound the cat is making.

> 오늘 아침도 바압 하고 우는 나초의 보챔으로 눈을 뜹니다.

Today, yet again, I opened my eyes to the whines of Nacho who was crying 'baaaab-'

If you wanted to see 하고 __는 as a pattern, then you could replace '_' with a verb related to speaking or making a noise, e.g. 부르다, 말 하다, 소리치다, 속삭이다, etc.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't related.

나초, the cat, is crying...

---

### From the verb `울다` *to cry*:

> 우는 새 *singing bird*
>
> 우는 아기 *crying baby*

---

### ~고 as a conjunctive ending

[The ~고 (*"and then"*) is **a conjunctive ending** connecting the order of the actions, first making the bap-meow and then crying or perhaps having the actions happen simultaneously...it can be interpreted about four different ways.](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3181/%ea%b3%a0-as-a-conjunctive-ending)

---

### ~도 conveys the meaning of inclusiveness

도 is like "too". She's indicating something like

> Today, too, I woke up to...

Here are other examples of how to use it with nouns:

- 저도 학생이예요 *I too am a student*
- 그는 테니스도 잘 쳐요 *He plays tennis well too*

### ~도 can also put emphasis when used with other particles, adverbs, or verbs

If used in this way, she's indicating something like

> Even today, I woke up to...

Here are some other examples of how to use it for emphasis:

- 일요일에도 회사에 나갑니다 *Even on Sunday we go to the office*
- 한국에도 친구가 많아요 *Even in Korea I have many friends*
- 저 기차는 빨리도 달리는군요 *That train runs very fast*

Comment: Nacho is a cat. So, if 하고 is just being used as a conjunction, I don't understand why they used "도" after "오늘 아침". "Also today and I open my eyes to the sound of Nacho crying". It would make more sense to me if they said something like "아침이고"   I thought 하고 was only used between nouns?

Comment: In "이것을 하고 저것을 해", "하고" can only be the verb "하다(do)" with -고 ending, i.e., "[I/you/someone] *do* this, and do that".  Note that 조사 "하고(and)" cannot occur together with to 을/를.  So if you want to use "하고(and)", it must be "이것**하고** 저것을 해".  (In that case I think 하고 can be read in two ways, either "do this *and* that" or "*do* this *and* do that".)

Comment: @jick this is interesting.  [can you help me understand this better please?(https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3181/%ea%b3%a0-as-a-conjunctive-ending)