# ~고 as a conjunctive ending

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

It was said on [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/%ed%95%98%ea%b3%a0-%eb%8a%94-grammatical-structure) in a comment that

> 조사 "하고(and)" cannot occur together with to 을/를. So if you want to use "하고(and)", it must be "이것하고 저것을 해"

Summarized from a book I have from 연세 University in Seoul, there are 4 ways to use ~고 as a conjunctive ending:

1. Two or more sentences are simply listed.
2. Two events take place concurrently.
3. Two events are in a temporal relationship. THe first event precedes the second.
4. Depending upon the verbs used, the first action still continues while the second takes place.

Examples:

1. 새가 울고 꽃이 핍니다 *Birds sing (cry), and flowers bloom*
2. 나는 피아노를 치고 동생은 노래를 불렀습니다 *I was playing the piano while my sister sang*
3. 손을 씻고 저녁 식사를 합니다 *(We) wash our hands and eat supper*
4. 형이 새 옷을 입고 외출했습니다 *My brother went out wearing new clothes*

From what I'm seeing here, ~고 is a conjunctive ending that fully separates two verbs.  How can two verbs separated by ~고 not then also themselves each have their own object to modify with or without 을/를?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood my comment.  (Well, that's the problem  with comments: it's too short and I can't go back to edit it.)

하고 can mean at least three different things:

1. The verb "하다" (do), with the suffix "-고" (... and).

   > 산책을 **하고** 집에 들어왔다.
2. 조사(particle?) "하고", with the same meaning as 와/과 (and).

   > 밥**하고** 미역국을 먹었다.
3. Used to quote someone.  (I think it's also 조사, but for some reason I can't find it in Naver dictionary.)

   > 선생님께서 "빨리 가자." **하고** 말씀하셨다.

In my comment, I'm talking about (2): 조사 "하고" cannot be used together with 은/는/이/가/을/를, even when it is attached to subjects or objects:

> 철수**하고** 영희가 도착했다. (O)
>
> 철수가하고 영희가 도착했다. (X)
>
> 선물**하고** 카드를 받았다. (O)
>
> 선물을하고 카드를 받았다. (X)

Therefore, if you see "-을/를 하고", then it can be only case (1), where "하고" is the verb "하다" + ending "-고".  Here are a few examples where they contrast:

> [밥**하고** 미역국]을 먹었다.  I ate rice and seaweed soup.
>
> [밥(을) **하고**] [전화를 걸었다].  I cooked rice, and made a call.
>
> [숙제**하고** 가방을] 차에 실었다.  I put my homework and backpack in the car.
>
> [숙제(를) **하고**] [가방을 차에 실었다.]  I did my homework, and put my backpack in the car.

As you can see, "숙제하고 가방을 차에 실었다" can be ambiguous.